# Code sign mac app, made with Director 12 - error - main executable failed strict validation

Tags: macos, adobe, sign

I encountered a strange and frustrating issue. 
I´m not able to code sign any new mac app projector made from Adobe Director 12, 
I code sign with this:
codesign -f -v -s "Developer ID Application: Statped" /Users/olleeriksen/Desktop/test/start.app
It always give the same error: 
/Users/olleeriksen/Desktop/test/start.app: **main executable failed strict validation**

I have a couple of .apps that I have been able to code sign, I can make changes and resign them, works perfect. So my certificates seems to be fine.
But if I republish these apps from Director 12, I will get the same issues..
I have published the mac app projectors from both my Mac and windows PC, same issues, no difference.

I´m using a new iMac with Yosemite 10.10.3

I have a small test app here:
[test app and workfiles](http://www.acm5.com/test/director/)

Anyone seen this before?